# Unable to search for published Knowledge articles in the Salesforce SDK on Android 10 (API 29)

Tags: android, sfdcmobilesdk-android, salesforce-sdk-android

we're using Salesforce Android SDK (version 224.0.0):
https://github.com/forcedotcom/ServiceSDK-Android/releases

And found out that text search through the knowledge articles doesn't work on Android 10 (API 29), but it's working on Android 9 (API 28).

Is it a known issue? Could we follow it up somewhere?

By the way, the link to submit a SDK-related case is broken here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000351538&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1

Thanks,
Stepan